# Weighted distribution of a pizza

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Lets say we have 4 friends who split a pizza each day. Person 1 gets 40%, person 2 gets 15%, person 3 get 20% and person 4 gets 25%. One day, Person 1 decides not to show up. Now the 3 friends must split Person 1's slice (40%) among themselves but they need to be given the weighted amount. I understand that .4/3 = ~13% but each person has a weighted share in the pizza for arbitrary reasons such as the percentage of money they add to the pool. What kind of problem is this? And how can this be solved?

My apologies if this is a repeat question but I am not sure what to search(google).

Thank you

Comment: By weighted share, do you mean share in the same ratio as before. Because then it is simply a question of 15:20:25 to be turned into percentages

Comment: Person 3 typically gets $\frac{4}{3}$ as much pizza as person 2 ... you need to make sure that in this new scenario that is still the case.

Comment: @mdave16 yes. I am hoping to keep the same ratio among the remaining three friends.

Comment: 1) the 3 friends usually eat $60\%% of the pizza.  Not the eat $100\%$.  That's $\frac {100}60} = 5/3$ more.  So the each eat $5/3$ times their normal amount.  2) 15% is *what* percent of 60%?  It is $\frac {15}{60} = \frac 14 = 25\%$.  (and as it turns out.  $15*\frac 53 = 25$ so both methods agree.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood I was doing 15/40 before which is why I got more confused over time. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

It seems natural to me to think of shares.  Person 1 has 40 shares, person 2 has 15 and so on.  Now person 1 has abandoned his claim, so there are only 60 shares instead of 100.  Person 2 then gets $\frac {15}{60}=25\%=\frac 14$.  Person 3 gets $\frac {20}{60}=\frac 13$.  Person 4 gets $\frac {25}{60}=\frac 5{12}$